# Multi-tenant SaaS built in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, multi-tenant, yii2-advanced-app

I am working in a multi-tenant software (SaaS) built with [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) on the Advanced Template, but I am not having the desired result about the tenants database connection.

I am trying to set the Database Connection as next in my config file for the frontend:

```
$defaultAdminDB = [
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=untitled',
  'username' => 'postgres',
  'password' => 'myPass',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
];

$config = [
  'components' => [
    'db' => function(){
      if (Yii::$app->session->get('login', false)){
        return [
          'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
          'dsn' => Yii::$app->session->get('client_connection.dns'),
          'username' => Yii::$app->session->get('client_connection.username'),
          'password' => Yii::$app->session->get('client_connection.password'),
          'charset' => 'utf8',
        ];
      }

      return [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=untitled',
        'username' => 'postgres',
        'password' => 'myPass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
      ];
    },
    'dbAdmin' => $defaultAdminDB
  ]
];
```

Then I have a two steps log in, where the first asks for the login (tenant id) and the next provides the user and password. On the first controller I do the next with:

```
$account = \frontend\models\AdminAccounts::findOne(['login'=>$this->login]);

if (!$account){
  $this->addError('login', Yii::t('app', 'Account data not found.'));
  return false;
}

$dns = sprintf('pgsql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $account->getAttribute('db_host'), $account->getAttribute('db'));

Yii::$app->session->set('login', $this->login);
Yii::$app->session->set('client_connection.dns', $dns);
Yii::$app->session->set('client_connection.username', $account->getAttribute('db_user'));
Yii::$app->session->set('client_connection.password', $account->getAttribute('db_pass'));
```

I get successfully the account (tenant) data and store it in session, but I guess my error is on instantiating the `yii\db\Connection` on the model's `getDb()` method.

Hope can help me.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Yii::$app->db = new \yii\db\Connection([
'dsn' => Yii::$app->session->get('client_connection.dsn'),
'username' => Yii::$app->session->get('client_connection.username'),
'password' => Yii::$app->session->get('client_connection.password'),
]);
```

Comment: can you explain what you did and why it answers the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the db connection info of an existing db connection then you should close the existing connection (Yii::$app->db->close()), change the connection info, and then open the new connection (Yii::$app->db->open()).